# route that will handle URL's in the URL for MVC 3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, url-routing, asp.net-mvc-routing

I am trying to create a custom route that can handle something like:

```
domain.com/link/http://www.someotherdomain.com/blablah.html?qstring=54
```

Where the passed param is a link...

I cannot get this to work with URL encode and decode.. always returns a bad request?

Answer (score 0):

Pass the link as id.

Something like...

controller:

```
public SomeAction(string url)
{
   ...
}
```

View:

```
@Html.ActionLink("link name", "Action", new {id = "someurl.com"}
```

or modify the global.asax's routes.MapRoute and add another parameter.

Comment: hi, there is a parameter and the url is encoded.. still doesn't work

Comment: Odd. Did you decode the url before passing it as string to the action in the controller? any snippets of the controller and view?